# What is the request size limitation on Safari under iOS 7?

Tags: asp.net, ios, safari

I have several C#.Net Webforms apps that can occasionally develop a rather large viewstate. In the past, with iOS 6, I had trouble with Safari truncating the viewstate on post-back, causing the application to throw an exception. All other browsers were unaffected of course. I could reproduce the problem, but not always reliably. I found conflicting opinions out there on whether Safari under iOS 6 was chopping off post parameters after the 32k mark or the 64k mark. Breaking the viewstate into chunks did help either. The size of the post as a whole is what mattered.

The official spec appears to be a mystery. Perhaps things change changed with iOS 7 though. **Does anyone know if this limitation is still in place and what it is?**

I am considering the rewrite of many pages in an application I inherited and am trying to figure out how small I need to keep my viewstate to make iPad and iPhone users happy. Of course they could be rewritten in MVC but that would take considerably more effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It set up a page in .NET to test this. It contained a button that added 1K of garbage to the Viewstate and then printed out it's current size in bytes. I was able to grow the viewstate to over 100K both in Safari on iOS 6 and 7 without any ill effects. This was the same regardless of whether I had viewstate set to break itself up into smaller chunks using maxPageStateFieldLength or not.

However, I was still able to get the page to throw invalid viewstate exceptions under iOS 6 with heavy use of the browser back button. This is likely due to Safari mobile too aggressively caching and using old requests. This particular bug appears to have been mitigated in iOS 7 though. It now in some cases brings up a dialog box asking if you want to resubmit the page. The bad viewstate error is then not triggered.

**So it appears that there is no limitation in request size per se**. A combination of this and other factors are required to trigger the invalid viewstate exceptions under Safari mobile and .Net.

Comment: Just as an update for iOS 8.1.1 for anyone who might stumble upon this. At the time of writing, viewstates over 200K consistently cause both Safari and Chrome to crash on post-back in my experience. This is using an iTouch and iPad Mini, both retina.